ESTA is not letting me pay
I started my daughter's ESTA application. Toward the end, at the payment process, the browser closed. Now when I go back to my application, there is no way I can pay and it does not allow me to create a new application as this one already exists.

What should I do?

Related/duplicate (but with different answers):  How to complete ESTA application when "THE PAYMENT STATUS COULD NOT BE DETERMINED AT THIS TIME"?

@MichaelSeifert can these two questions, including answers, be merged? Both seem useful.

@SaaruLindestøkke:  I don't have the authority to do so, and I'm not sure what the policy is.  You could always hit the "Flag" button above, say that it's "In need of moderator intervention", and see what the mods say.

Email esta@cbp.dhs.gov with the title "Urgent! ESTA payment issue", attach the screenshot and explain it like you did here. Ask them to get back to you and advise how to proceed.

very fast respond in the email you gave me. thanks

@asmgx What did they say?

They offered to cancel it and then i made a new application

I Followed the instructions of Crazydre.

Sent an email to esta@cbp.dhs.gov with the subject Urgent! ESTA payment issue.
Received a response in less than 5 minutes asking what actions I wanted them to take.
Requested them to cancel my application.
Submitted a new application.
Received ESTA approval within 1 hour.

